# Issues converting String to Date in Java

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat, parseexception

I need to convert an array of strings into the type Date in Java. I looked up some sample codes, which they all pretty much ask to do the same straight forward thing.
This is what I'm doing:

```
  String[] dateString = { "2014/05/01", "2014/05/02", "2014/05/03", "2014/05/04", "2014/05/05"};
        Date[] dt = new Date[5];
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
            dt[i]= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd").parse(dateString[i]);
        }
```

The issue is on the line inside the loop I get an error that states: "Unhandled Exception by ParseException". Eclipse suggests me to surround it with a try and catch block, which I did. It now runs, but the dates I am getting in the dt array are not matching to the ones I'm putting in. I guess I am getting some kind of default value, which starts and January 1st 2014.

Anyone know what this is and how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: mm is minutes, try MM

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use capital `MM` for month; `mm` is minutes.

- [`SimpleDateFormat` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) has all the symbols

Comment: Ohhh! Now it worked! Originally I had it all in capital letters, but I got an exception because of the Ys, so I put it all in lower case. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the case makes a difference for each letter code.

Answer (score 1):

For **month**, you need to use `MM`, not `mm`. `mm` represents **minutes**

Check this [Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Originally had it liked that, but changed it all after I got an exception because of the capital Ys...